# Reset Raspian No Monitor

Tags: raspbian

I have a raspberry pi that was setup at my old place. I would always connect using ssh over the wifi or my monitor.

I'm now in a situation where I don't have a monitor and I'm on a new network. I'm having issues with the password on the device when I try to ssh. I don't have anything I need on the device. Is it possible to reset the device without having a monitor?

Comment: If this is due to the change of your wifi network that the settings on your Raspberry Pi wpa_supplicant.conf no longer correct, you can try to step 2 of my [reply](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/62896/58715) to anther question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way that might avoid SD card damage.

If you look on the Raspberry Pi, you will find a 2-pin jumper labeled `RUN`. Where it is depends on the model. If you bridge the two pins, it will reset the processor.

For the Pi Zero/Zero W, it's right next to the camera connector, for the Pi 3B, it's by where the GPIO header comes close to the USB ports, and for the Pi B+/2B it's next to the status LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

No monitor, no network connection. Hopeless situation.
You must turn it off and hope to avoid problems with the file system.